# how to use a filter field to search a listbox vba

Tags: vba, listbox, ms-word, userform

I have a userform in a Word template that has a listbox on it. The listbox is initialised with a list of folder names read from within a main folder, and the user can select one from this list. Currently, the list is about a dozen entries, so scrolling down is not a problem, but I have been told that the final list will be about 250, which makes scrolling a tad weak.

How can I add a text field that the user can type in a reference number [The folder name is a reference number followed by a product name], which then filters the list for them to select from?

I'm thinking I need the folder list loaded into an array instead of the listbox, then a function that the text field contents will filter and reduce the list in the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

i had very similar request, im adding the code that i wrote to cope with that issue. the logic is very similar.  also, i am using excel so i have worksheet that is updating with all the search values ("your dataBase WorkSheet")
also i populated the results to a listview and not a listbox, but populating to listbox is much more easier. also note that the parameter that im passing to the function 'columnNum' is because the user can search via multiple search parameters(serial number, product name etc..). also, because you are not using excel, possible solution to replace the dataBase Worksheet is to define multidiamentional array with all the parameters, and to search it with a second array - just like 'dbarray' in the code below.
and if you will add your code it will be possible to convert this logic to your macro

```
     Public Function Search(ByVal columnNum As Byte, ByVal StringToSearch As  String) As Integer

     Dim numOfResults As Integer

     Dim lrdatabase As Long
     Dim dbarray() As Variant
     lrdatabase = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your dataBase WorkSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

' count how many results in order to preserve them in the next loop
Dim counter As Integer
For X = 2 To lrdatabase
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your dataBase WorkSheet").Cells(X, columnNum).Value Like "*" & StringToSearch & "*" Then
counter = counter + 1
End If
Next X

If counter = 0 Then
' there are no results
MsgBox "no result found" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "please note the search value is case sensitive", vbInformation + vbMsgBoxRight, "àéï úåöàåú"
     Search = 0
Exit Function
Else
numOfResults = counter
' because there are results the listview will clean
ClenListView
End If


ReDim Preserve dbarray(o To counter, 0 To 10) As Variant
counter = 0

For X = 2 To lrdatabase
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your dataBase WorkSheet").Cells(X, columnNum).Value Like "*" & StringToSearch & "*" Then
dbarray(counter, 0) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your dataBase WorkSheet").Cells(X, 9).Value
dbarray(counter, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your dataBase WorkSheet").Cells(X, 10).Value
dbarray(counter, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your dataBase WorkSheet").Cells(X, 11).Value
dbarray(counter, 3) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your dataBase WorkSheet").Cells(X, 12).Value
dbarray(counter, 4) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your dataBase WorkSheet").Cells(X, 13).Value
dbarray(counter, 5) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your dataBase WorkSheet").Cells(X, 14).Value
dbarray(counter, 6) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your dataBase WorkSheet").Cells(X, 15).Value
dbarray(counter, 7) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your dataBase WorkSheet").Cells(X, 16).Value
dbarray(counter, 8) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your dataBase WorkSheet").Cells(X, 17).Value
dbarray(counter, 9) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your dataBase WorkSheet").Cells(X, 18).Value
dbarray(counter, 10) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your dataBase WorkSheet").Cells(X, 19).Value

counter = counter + 1
End If
Next X


'listview shape
With ListView1
.View = lvwReport
.Gridlines = True
.FullRowSelect = True
   End With

   ' add header / headers text
HeadersForListView


' fill rows
'add items(first column) and sub items(the rest of the columns)
Dim itm As ListItem
   Dim rowndx As Long
   For rowndx = LBound(dbarray, 1) To UBound(dbarray, 1) - 2
   Set itm = ListView1.ListItems.Add
 itm = dbarray(rowndx, 0)
    itm.SubItems(1) = dbarray(rowndx, 1)
    itm.SubItems(2) = dbarray(rowndx, 2)
    itm.SubItems(3) = dbarray(rowndx, 3)
    itm.SubItems(4) = dbarray(rowndx, 4)
    itm.SubItems(5) = dbarray(rowndx, 5)
    itm.SubItems(6) = dbarray(rowndx, 6)
    itm.SubItems(7) = dbarray(rowndx, 7)
  itm.SubItems(8) = dbarray(rowndx, 8)
    itm.SubItems(9) = dbarray(rowndx, 9)
   itm.SubItems(10) = dbarray(rowndx, 10)

   Next rowndx



Me.ListView1.LabelEdit = lvwManual 'prevent the user to change the item text on the listview
Erase dbarray()
Search = numOfResults
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll see if I can adapt it. As I'm not using Excel, I don't have the benefit of a sheet to read, which would be good. I don't have a lot of experience with arrays. I can create the array, but I'm not sure how I can get a filter to work with it to reduce the results.